# Is the variance of sample median lower than the variance of any individual observation?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be random variables with common variance $\sigma^2$. It is easy to see that irrespective of our knowledge about the distribution or dependence structure of $X_i$'s, the variance of any weighted sample average, $\sum_{i=1}^n w_iX_i$ where $w_i\in[0,1],\sum_{i=1}^n w_i=1$, is at most $\sigma^2$, and hence any weighted average is better (in variance sense) than any individual $X_i$.

But what can we say about the variance of another commonly used measure of central tendency, the sample median? Remember that I am not assuming any dependence structure among $X_i$'s. Can we say that the variance of the sample median is at most $\sigma^2$? Assume for simplicity that each $X_i$ is symmetric if you want.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Sampling_distribution

Comment: I do not assume that $X_i$ are iid. In the worst case when $X_i$ are all same, the result you linked to will fail.

Comment: If $X_i$ are IID from density with $f(\eta) > 0.$ then sample median $H$ is asymptotically normal with variance $c^2/n,$ where $c = 1/(2f(\eta)).$ So variance of sample mean should decrease with increasing $n.$ // But as @LandonCarter comments, without some regularity assumptions the question has no answer..

Answer (score 1):

*Comment continued with simulation:* Assume you have $n = 100$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=100,\sigma=15),$ so that $Var(X_i) = 15^2 = 225$ and population median is $\eta = 100.$

```
set.seed(122)
h = replicate(10^5, median(rnorm(100, 100, 15)))
mean(h);  var(h);  sd(h)
[1] 100.003
[1] 3.490295
[1] 1.868233
```

So the variance $3.49$ of the median of 100 observations
is smaller that the variance $225$ of an individual observation.

*Notes:* (1) However $n = 100$ is not large enough
to achieve the asymptotic variance quoted in my comment.

(2) The variance of the sample mean $\bar X_{100} = \sigma^2/n = 225/100 = 2.25 < 3.49, $ the variance of the sample median of 100 observations.

Comment: I know this asymptotic result. But my question is, what about the variance of median of a bunch of observations?

Comment: If by a "bunch" you mean non-IID 'observations' from unknown distributions, then I know of no answer. Please clarify your question. // Do you have a specific application in mind?